# Ubuntu 13.10 blank screen with cursor after installing libopencv-dev

Tags: 13.10, intel-graphics, opencv

After installing `libopencv-dev` from the Ubuntu repository, I get a blank screen with cursor after logging into a session (after restarting the computer). I think there were some Nvidia-related packages installed. I don't know if it has anything to do with it. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with Intel HD 4000 graphics.

EDIT: Ok the problem was a `libopencv-dev` bug that installs Nvidia packages on non Nvidia graphics machines, causing the blank screen problem. To fix this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-319*
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If I may make a suggestion. Copy your solution as an answer and accept it as *the* solution. It might very well be that someone else has your very same problem and would thus see that this question solved and how to go about it.

Comment: Duplicate question was answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/401384/error-ubuntu-13-10-blackscreen/408064#408064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was a libopencv-dev bug that installs Nvidia packages on non Nvidia graphics machines, causing the blank screen problem. To fix this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-319*
```