# Error Ubuntu 13.10 blackscreen

Tags: installation, eclipse, opencv

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my PC recently, also installed Eclipse, Qt Creator, Blender and Synaptic (to download all the packages in order to work with OpenCV) everything went fine until i shut down the computer and then later, when i tried to log in Ubuntu, put my password an everything, the screen went black, and only the pointer appeared.. Tried several things to fix it but nothing work so i re-installed Ubuntu, and all the programs again but testing re-starting the computer after every installation, and all of them work except for the OpenCV packages, after installing them the blackscreen problem came back.

If anyone can help me please i'll appreciated a lot

Comment: You say "only the pointer appeared." If you're talking about the mouse arrow/cursor, and it is appearing on top of a *desktop* (which would appear black if you set your desktop to a black background), then you might be experiencing the problem described in [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/22949).

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an issue with an Intel graphics chip and the nvidia packages someone made libopencv-dev depend on (at least, that was the issue for me).

You need to get a generic version of libopencl1, which can be had in the package `ocl-icd-libopencl1`. Just run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-libopencl1
```

Then run:
    sudo apt-get autoremove
...which removes the packages that `libopencv-dev` depends on but which are now satisfied by the generic package you just installed.

If you rebooted before installing `ocl-icd-libopencl1` and after installing `libopencv-dev`, your desktop is probably still messed up. If you see a blank black screen with your mouse pointer on it after following the steps above, re-install `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity` and reboot. Then, if you see a graphical desktop without Unity running, you will need to install the Compiz config tool:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

Reboot once again, then when you get to your Unity-free desktop, hit `Ctrl-t` to open a terminal and run:

ccsm

This will start the Compiz settings manager. Find the Unity plugin button, click it, and re-enable it by checking the check box on the left. Voila! Unity lives again.

This is recorded at [my blog](http://www.anickle.com/?p=123). Hopefully the launchpad bug report on this fixes the issue, but if you get the time, you may run over there and make sure they know it effected you too.